# how can 20 edit texts keep their changed value on screen orientation change?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-orientation

I have a table. Each row in the table has editText. I change the value of the editTexts but when the orientation of the screen changes, edit text looses the value i just typed in and have the default value.
Any idea how can edit texts keep the typed value on screen orientation change?

I dont want to do this for 20 values:

```
   @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putString("myObj", myObj);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is the simplest way to retain that value you can try others but they are going to be more painful

Comment: You could save an array of strings instead?

Comment: @c_user89 : How are you creating your layout? In an XML layout file or dynamically  in code?

Comment: You can stop it from changing orientation

Comment: i created a string of arrays. thanks for your help!

Comment: try adding this to your activity inside manifest android:configChanges="screenOrientation" this will prevent reloading of screen after orientation change